# recurly - finding accounts

Tags: python, recurly

I want to know how can I search for a particular account in my recurly system? I am using the latest python recurly module, 2.8.3... but I see no recurly method for searching/finding an account.  I at first thought I could do:

```
import recurly

# {set key, subdomain, and default currency params here.}

userAccount = recurly.Account(account_code="acc code")
```

but this doesn't do anything, it just creates an empty recurly account object.

Is there a search or find method for accounts?

I am blind, and unfortunately https://dev.recurly.com/docs makes my web browser choke and often times it brings my computer to a huge lag, or locks up completely.  and my pc is no slouch in the cpu/ram department.  So I am having a difficult time reading the various python examples.  I wish there was just a document for recurly via the python module.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurly example from their site is:

```
try:
  account = recurly.Account.get('1')
  print "Account: %s" % account
except NotFoundError:
  print "Account not found.\n"
```

So you just missed the .get